# Powershell Bytes to Bit Array

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, powershell-4.0, bitarray

I'm having an issue turning ByteArrays into Bits and then bringing them back. Eventually I'm trying to go from ByteArray to Hex and then back but I'm having getting different values back than I'm putting in.

This is the BitArray Setup:

```
$list = @(1,7,10,11,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,29,30,32,33,37,39,41,42,43,44,46,48,49,54,56,60,69,72,74,77,79,88,98,100,102,104,109,114,116,118,119,120,127,128,129,133,135,143,147)
$BitArray = New-Object BitArray(152)
$list | % {$BitArray[$_ - 1] = $true}
```

Note: I'm using some custom type-accelerators

```
if ($(try{[accelerators]}catch{"nope"}) -eq "nope"){
  $xlr=[psobject].Assembly.GetType('System.Management.Automation.TypeAccelerators')
  $xlr::Add('accelerators',([psobject].Assembly.GetType('System.Management.Automation.TypeAccelerators')))
}
@{
  "datatable"="System.ComponentModel.MarshalByValueComponent"
  "marshal"="System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal"
  "BitArray"="System.Collections.BitArray"
}.GetEnumerator() | %{
  $AcceleratorName=$_.name
  $AcceleratorValue=$_.value
  if (-not ((([accelerators]::get).keys | ? {$_ -eq "$AcceleratorName"} | Measure-Object).count)){
    [accelerators]::add("$AcceleratorName","$AcceleratorValue")
  }
}
```

Based on what I've found I've used this to convert to Bytes:

```
$result =  New-Object System.Byte[] (19)
$BitArray.CopyTo($result, 0)
```

But when I turn them both into strings they don't match up.

Input to String code:

```
$array = @()
0..151 | % {if ($BitArray[$_]) {$array += 1} else {$array += 0}}

$InputAsArray = @()
0..18 | % {
    $InputAsArray += ($array -join "").Substring(($_ * 8),8)
}
```

Output to String code:

```
($result | % { [Convert]::ToString($_, 2).PadRight(8,'0')})
```

Input Pattern:

```
10000010
01101111
11111110
00001101
10001010
11110101
10000101
00010000
00001001
01001010
00000001
00000000
01010101
00001000
01010111
00000011
10001010
00000010
00100000
```

Output Pattern:

```
10000010
11110110
11111110
10110000
10100010
10101111
10100001
10000000
10010000
10100100
10000000
00000000
10101010
10000000
11101010
11000000
10100010
10000000
10000000
```

Comment: `[Convert]::ToString($_, 2)` -> `$($ca=[Convert]::ToString($_, 2).ToCharArray(); [Array]::Reverse($ca); New-Object String (,$ca))`

Comment: Bytes to bits: `$bytes = [byte[]]@(0,1,2,3,4,5); $bits = [Collections.BitArray]$bytes`. Bits to bytes: `$bytes = [byte[]]::new([Math]::floor(($bits.length-1)/8)+1); $bits.copyTo($bytes,0)`. There's a lot of code in your question that I've failed to connect to the original goal of `turning ByteArrays into Bits and then bringing them back`.

Comment: @PetSerAl Reversing it doesn't work, also that omits the padding.

Comment: @user3661504 I am not omit padding. I replace only `[Convert]::ToString($_, 2)` part.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems with your code currently.

As hinted by @PetSerAl, `BitArray.CopyTo()` seems to reverse the order/endianness.

This is the function I personally use (ported from [this C# extension method](http://geekswithblogs.net/dbrown/archive/2009/04/05/convert-a-bitarray-to-byte-in-c.aspx)):

```
function ConvertTo-ByteArray {

    param([System.Collections.BitArray]$BitArray)

    $numBytes = [System.Math]::Ceiling($BitArray.Count / 8)

    $bytes = New-Object byte[] $numBytes
    $byteIndex = 0 
    $bitIndex = 0

    for ($i = 0; $i -lt $BitArray.Count; $i++) {
        if ($BitArray[$i]){
            $bytes[$byteIndex] = $bytes[$byteIndex] -bor (1 -shl (7 - $bitIndex))
        }
        $bitIndex++
        if ($bitIndex -eq 8) {
            $bitIndex = 0
            $byteIndex++
        }
    }

    ,$bytes
}
```

---

Your second problem is not the conversion itself, but the way you add padding to the `byte` strings:

```
[Convert]::ToString($_, 2).PadRight(8,'0')
```

`PadRight()` will add zeroes to the *end* of the string, rather than at the start.

Change it to `PadLeft()` and you'll get the correct output:

```
($result | % { [Convert]::ToString($_, 2).PadLeft(8,'0')})
```

Comment: If you just replace `PadRight` to `PadLeft`, then result still be different from code, which convert `$BitArray` to string.

Comment: @PetSerAl You're right, I used my own function to convert the BitArray to `[byte[]]` which gave the expected result

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Thanks! With that code it works and I'm able to go round-trip back to a BitArray as below:

    `$SecondBitArray = New-Object BitArray(152);
    $SecondBitArray = (($result | % { [Convert]::ToString($_, 2).PadLeft(8,'0')}) -join "" -split"(?<=\d)(?=\d)") | % {[bool][int]$_}`

Comment: IMHO, it is not `BitArray.CopyTo` fault. It is OP putting least significant (least index) bits first when converting from `$BitArray`. But `[Convert]::ToString` put least significant bits last, because humans write down numbers this way.

Comment: @PetSerAl agreed, should probably update the answer to reflect that

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to do it using split with regular expression. 
After this statement:

```
$List | % {$BitArray[$_ - 1] = $True}
```

Create another array (or string) with ones and zeros

```
0..($BitArray.Count -1) | % {if ($BitArray[$_]) {$strBitArray += @("1")} else {$strBitArray += @("0")}}
```

Use regular expression to chop the string up into 8 bit chunks:

```
$ByteArray = $strBitArray  -join('') -split '(?<=\G[01]{8})(?=.)' | %{[convert]::ToInt64($_,2)}
```